# Relation between $m^{***}$ with $m^*$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For any set $A$, define $m^{***} (A)\in [0, \infty]$ by
$$m^{***}(A)=\sup \{m^*(F) \mid F \subseteq A, F \text{  is closed } \}$$

So how is $m^{***}$ related to outer measure $m^*$?

There is a similar question already exists [how are $m^{**}(E)$ and $m^{***}(E)$ related to $m^{*}(E)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123646/how-are-me-and-me-related-to-me)
said that $m^{***}=m^{**}=m^*$

However, the hint "Regularity theorem for Lebesgue measure" is kind of new to me. I have already proved $m^{**}=m^*$ in that question, and also in my problem, it's easy to see that $m^{***} \leq m^*$. However, I am not sure how to process the other direction. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelLee Thanks, I am reading it. Could you give me more hint about how to use it?

Comment: I'm writing an answer now!

Comment: @MichaelLee Thanks!

Comment: Your question looks like Problems 22 and 23 in _Real Analysis_, fourth edition, by Royden and Fitzpatrick. If you are indeed using that textbook, Problem 17 is the regularity theorem for Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a theorem from Tao's measure theory book that states the following to be equivalent for $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$:

1. $E$ is Lebesgue measurable.
2. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an open set $U\supset E$ such that $m^*(U\setminus E) < \epsilon$.
3. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $m^*(E\Delta U) < \epsilon$.
4. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a closed set $F\subset E$ such that $m^*(E\setminus F) < \epsilon$.
5. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a closed set $F\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $m^*(E\Delta F) < \epsilon$.
6. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a Lebesgue measurable set $E_{\epsilon}$ such that $m^*(E_{\epsilon}\Delta E) < \epsilon$.

This is essentially the regularity theorem for the Lebesgue measure. For a proof, look at Exercise 1.2.7 [here](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~bahra004/for-real/real-hw1.pdf). As you have already shown, $m^*$ and $m^{**}$ are equivalent definitions of the Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb{R}$ ($m^{**}$ is the more general definition for arbitrary Euclidean spaces). It is easy to show using the above theorem that the Lebesgue inner measure and Lebesgue outer measure are equal for Lebesgue measurable sets; namely, for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose a closed set $F\subseteq E$ and an open set $U\supseteq E$ such that $$m^{***}(E)\geq m^*(F)\geq m(E)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ and $$m^{**}(E)\leq m^*(U)\leq m(E)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ As this is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, we will have $m^{**}(E)\leq m(E)\leq m^{***}(E)$. Combined with the more obvious inequality $m^{***}(E)\leq m(E)\leq m^{**}(E)$, we will have $m^{**} = m^{***} = m$ for Lebesgue measurable sets. When $E$ is not Lebesgue measurable, however, the inner and outer measure will not agree.

Comment: In 4, we assume E is measurable, however, there is no such assumption for $A$ here.

Comment: How are you defining $m^*$, $m^{**}$, and $m^{***}$ then? Your definition of $m^{***}$ is the definition of the Lebesgue inner measure, which will only be equal to the outer measure if the set is Lebesgue measurable (this is the definition of Lebesgue measurability). From what I can tell, in the linked question, $m^*$ is defined as the Lebesgue measure, $m^{**}$ the outer measure, and $m^{***}$ the inner measure.

Comment: This is a problem on a textbook, it defined $m^{***}$ as I gave here, no more assumptions. So I guess maybe there is no equal relation here?

Comment: For $m^*$ the Lebesgue measure, if $m^*(E)$ is well-defined, then $m^*(E) = m^{***}(E)$. I don't see any problem with the question as written, so long as it is understood that $m^*$ is the Lebesgue measure, and therefore it only makes sense to ask about the relationship between $m^*$ and $m^{***}$ on Lebesgue measurable sets.

Comment: The question is asked about the relation between $m^{***}$ and the outer measure here, not Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I think the linked question also define $m^{*}$ as outer measure.

Comment: No, the linked question defined $m^{**}$ as outer measure.

Comment: If you'd like, I can answer the question for the inner measure (which you have written) and the outer measure, but that equality holds iff $E$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Yes and no, since $m^{**}$ always equal to the outer measure $m^{*}$.

Comment: You're missing the point. The definition of the outer measure of $E$ is the infimum of the measures of the open covers of $E$. This is how $m^{**}$ is defined in the linked question. If $m^*$ is defined differently from $m^{**}$, then $m^*$ is not the outer measure.

Comment: http://math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/books/royden-fitzpatrick/royden-fitzpatrick.pdf here is the link for the textbook, if you could look at page 43, problem 22 and 23, you would know what I mean. Yes, you are absolutely right, the definition of $m^{**}$ is the outer measure. However, these two questions asked about the relation between $m^{**}$, $m^{***}$ and the outer measure $m^{*}$.

Comment: So I guess it's better to say that $m^{**}=m^{*}$ always, and $m^{***}=m^{*}$ when $A$ is measurable?

Comment: I see. I would say that that statement is exactly correct, then. I'll revise this answer to reflect that.

Comment: Very appreciate!

Comment: No problem! Hope this is more explanatory.