# Does $m^{***}(A)=m^*(A)$ imply that $A$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to solve an exercise from Royden's *Real Analysis, 4th ed.*

> For any set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, define $m^{***}(A)=sup\{m^*(F):F\subseteq A$ is a closed set$\}$. How is this set function $m^{***}$ related to outer measure $m^*$?

I am aware that this exercise [Relation between $m^{***}$ with $m^*$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375213/relation-between-m-with-m) has been discussed before on SE, yet I do not find it satisfactory because I am not assuming per se that $A$ is measurable.

---

**Relevant definitions and theorems**

Keep in mind that Royden defines outer measure $m^*(A)=inf\{\sum _{i=1}^ \infty l(I_i):$ $I_1,I_2,...$ is a sequence of nonempty, bounded, open intervals whose union covers $A$}. This is defined regardless of whether $A$ is measurable or not.

It has also been proven that we have five equivalent definitions of measurability:

> The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\forall A \subseteq \mathbb{R}[m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A \cap E^c)]$
> 2. $\forall \epsilon >0\exists$ open set $O \supseteq E$[$m^*(O-E)< \epsilon]$
> 3. $\exists G_δ$ set $G \supseteq E[m^*(G-E)=0]$
> 4. $\forall \epsilon >0\exists$ closed set $F \subseteq E$[$m^*(E-F)< \epsilon]$
> 5. $\exists F_σ$ set $F \subseteq E[m^*(E-F)=0]$

Now we tackle the actual problem...

---

**My progress so far**

We always have $m^{***}(A) \leq m^*(A)$ obviously. I have formulated the following conjecture:

> $m^{***}(A)=m^*(A)$ if and only if $A$ is measurable.

I have shown that $A$ measurable implies $m^{***}(A)=m^*(A)$.

For the other direction, I have managed to show that $m^{***}(A)=m^*(A)$ implies $A$ is measurable in the special case that $m^*(A)< \infty$. But if $m^*(A)= \infty$, I don't know how to show it.

I was able to prove the finite case by finding some $F_δ$ set $F\subseteq A$ having the same measure as $A$, observing that $m^*(A)=m^*(A-F)+m^*(F)=m^*(A-F)+m^*(A)$, and subtracting $m^*(A)$ from each side to obtain $m^*(A-F)=0$ (meaning that $A$ is meaurable).

If $m^*(A)= \infty$, I don't know what to since I obviously can't subtract $\infty$ from both sides.

Comment: For the finite case, how did you justify that $m^*(A) = m^*(A-F) + m^*(F)$? Outer measure isn't additive in general for nonmeasurable sets, only subadditive.

Comment: @Bungo I used that fact that $F$ is measurable, which implies that $m^*(A)=m^*(A \cap F^c)+m^*(A \cap F)$.

Comment: Ah right, thanks.

Comment: Just to point you in the right direction, you would need compact sets instead of just closed sets for Euclidean space.

Comment: Use the fact that $\mathbb R$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @Matematleta Please elaborate. I think you were suggesting that I write $A$ as a countable union of disjoint, finite sets, but I'm skeptical that each of these finite sets will be measurable.

Comment: You've shown that $A$ is measurable, so so is $[-n,n]\cap A$ for each $n$, and therefore so is $A=\bigcup_n [-n,n]\cap A$.

Comment: @Matematleta No, I have shown that **if** $A$ is measurable then $m***(A)=m*(A)$. I am now trying to prove the converse, which is where I am stuck.